# How to bring ImageView in front of other ImageViews (android)

Tags: android

I have list of images added in a `LinearLayout`

```
+------------+
|  Image 1   |
+------------+
|  Image 2   |
+------------+
|  Image 3   |
+------------+
```

I want every 2nd image to get Displayed above 1st and 3rd Image.
For that I have set Bottom Margin of `Image 1` to `-10` pixels so `Image 2` overrides `Image 1` and it works, but this same logic does not work for  `Image 3`, `Image 2` does not override  `Image 3`s Top portion, as i have given `-10` top margin for the `Image 3`.

I have also tried `bring_to_front` for `Image 2` but it does not work.
How Should i get it working.

Thanks,
PP.

Comment: I can't Change the layout, I have to Use LinearLayout.

Comment: Also check [this answer][1] for a quick example.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929412/android-layout-layers-z-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) will be an ideal choice for such a case. It allows z-ordering of child views and will stack all the view over one another. Using `view#setVisibility(...)` you can toggle visibility of your views to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

use framelayout(it is like div tag in html)

links:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html
http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/02/frame-layout.html