# Z indexing image view over another Image view (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I was worried if an Image view over another image view can be z-indexed? and brought to front or back. Is there any options for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use frame layout to achieve that.  Have a look a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929412/android-layout-layers-z-axis)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one ImageView for that.
If you want to switch between images in an ImageView you can use a [LevelListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList).
If you want all images to be drawn in a certain z-order you can use a [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList).