# How does overlaying views work in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, overlay, uinavigationbar

In Android, i noticed that you can have a fixed view on top of another. For example, when you open your browser, and tap the search box, a keyboard prompt pops up (on top of a listview). However, notice that you can still scroll up and down on the listview without the keyboard going away. Like:

[image: example showing keyboard overlaying the listview]

would someone please explain (preferrably some sample code in addition) how this works?

What i'm trying to do is just have a custom listview that always has a floating navigation bar on top of the listview and also on the bottom of the list view (it's not actually a header/footer of the listview, it's more like a header/footer of the screen). It would be similar to the example i just described, where the user can interact with both the navigation bar as well as the listview "underneath" the nav bar.

I am somewhat new to Android development, so please be nice and provide a little bit of details if you would :) much thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whoops. looks like someone had a similar issue:

[Layout Layers? Z-Axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929412/android-layout-layers-z-axis)

and this post http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html  explains how FrameLayout works and also how  works, which is an even better alternative.

FrameLayout lays object in a different Z-axis, so this is the solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that, the simpler i can think of is using linear layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/header">
      //Here you add whatever you want in your "header"
    </LinearLayout>

    //create your listview
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/content_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
   />

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/footer">
      //Here you add whatever you want in your "footer"
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. while that particular XML looks like it'll work for that particular screen, it won't work when the user dismisses the keyboard. i apologize that my question didn't really specify this point, my fault. what i'm trying to achieve is actually overlaying two views on top of each other, not flattening them out to 1 view -> the reason being i need to create one particular overlaying navigation header view on top of any views in my app. i was hoping there was an easy way to do this if i knew how to overlay 2 views