# How to custom logo on Android actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to custom a logo using actionbarsherlock so the logo
would be like the following image

I want the logo to overflow the actionbar ... any solutions ?

[image]

Comment: I don't know how the `actionbarsherlock` works, but I guess it uses some kind of a background drawable. If it does, you can replace it with your own, in which the logo overlaps the bar.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705414/changing-the-action-bar-icon or rather http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131045/how-do-i-have-an-actionbar-icon-logo-that-overlaps-the-content-as-well