# Can I control the z axis in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

What's the best way to have control of the Z-axis in Android?

Here: [Layout Layers? Z-Axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929412/android-layout-layers-z-axis), it states that the best way would be using a FrameLayout. Me, I managed to used a RelativeLayout with the following structure:

```
RelativeLayout
-- LinearLayout
-- -- View v1 (bottom)
-- -- View v2 (bottom)
-- LinearLayout
-- -- View v3 (top)
```

But this doesn't answer fully my question. What happens when I want my View v1 to be always on top, but View v3 to be always on top of View v2.

Like this:

```
RelativeLayout
-- LinearLayout
-- -- View v1 z=1
-- -- View v2 z=3
-- LinearLayout
-- -- View v3 z=2
```

(where 1 on top of 2 on top of 3)

This was easily done in Flex... can it be done in Android dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), not RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

Anyway in Android having Views in top of others really makes no sense. Use `View.setVisibility(View.GONE)` to tell Android to not draw a View (it won't reserve space for it) and `View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to make it draw it.

Comment: when you have an animation that passes through your nicely "layered" interface, it makes sense ;)

Comment: No, it does not ;) As I said, you can do that with GONE/VISIBLE. I actually do that: I flip the whole layout and it shows the next layout like it was behind (a 3D flip on Y axis).

Answer (score 1):

You can define the translationZ parameter in the .xml file. 
A higher value indicates a "nearer position towards the user":

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:translationZ="2dp">
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-22dp"
    android:translationZ="1dp"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

I found this useful when shifting a ListView beneath a graphic with transparency (in conjunction with a negative margin) to make it look like it disappears behind the line as can be seen below:

[image: Example for usage of translationZ]

Comment: Works only from api >= 21, for below View.bringToFront() should help