# Imageview on top of another imageview or not?

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

I have two Image views view1,view2.view1 is the black image and view2 is the white image.
Here view1 is single in the 1st image.view2 is over view1 in 2nd image.

1) How I check that view1 is single(in 1st image),no other view is on top of it?

2) How I check that view1 is not single(in 2nd image), another view is on top of it?

Comment: You can just check the visibility of the 2 views

Comment: How? can u give some code plz?

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to check for z-axis, refer to this question and use a FrameLayout: [Layout Layers? Z-Axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929412/android-layout-layers-z-axis)

```
<FrameLayout>
  <RelativeLayout>
    <!--  Place the objects you want on the bottom here -->
  </RelativeLayout>


  <RelativeLayout>
    <!--  Place the objects you want on the top here -->
  </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

As the other point out then you have to make the inner View VISIBLE or INVISIBLE.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may check the visibility of both imageviews no matter if one is on top of the other.

```
//...
ImageView v1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view1);
ImageView v2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view2);

if(v2.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
   //The view v2 is not visible so V1 is alone
else
   //Both views are visible
```

If v2 is not visible it won't be on top of the first view.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
ImageView outer = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.outer);
ImageView inner = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.inner);

// Do all your overlapping code here

// When you want to check if they are visible try something like this :
if (View.VISIBLE == inner.isVisible())
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the the image when the user interacts with it (e.g. you have a check box and you want to have imageview1 when is checked and imageview2 when is not checked) then you should add in *res/drawable* a file containing a selector (where radio_selected is the picture from imageView1 and radio_deselected is the picture from imageView2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_select" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_deselect"/>
 <!-- default not pressed -->

</selector>
```

You will have a single imageView with the background set to the name of the file containing the above selector. This way, the state will change automatically and so will the images, when the user interacts with the control.

Please tell me if you need any help with this approach.