# How to make second layout on top of glview (openGL)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, opengl-es, webview

I am trying to set other layout (in my case: a WebView) on top of my glView.

```
glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
glView.setRenderer(this);
setContentView(glView);
```

I searched and read articles about this and as all suggest that i should do :

1. set content view for my glview
2. add content view (as parent view) (relative layout)
3. add webview inside my parent view

I followed the suggestion as follows:

`glview is declared in other class file (as i wrote above)`

then in my actual class....

```
  webView = new WebView(glGame);
  glGame.addContentView(rl, null);
  rl.addView(webView);
```

However, I got this error :

```
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 23363
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$PrivateHandler.<init>(WebViewClassic.java:12520)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.<init>(WebViewClassic.java:2144)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebViewClassic$Factory.createWebView(WebViewClassic.java:3021)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:1980)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2033)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3381)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3434)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:446)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:510)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:487)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:468)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:457)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:447)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at com.phielosoft.androidgames.jnftt.LevelScreen.<init>(LevelScreen.java:38)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at com.phielosoft.androidgames.jnftt.MainMenuScreen.update(MainMenuScreen.java:50)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at com.phielosoft.androidgames.framework.impl.GLGame.onDrawFrame(GLGame.java:93)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1524)
08-26 19:37:21.855: E/AndroidRuntime(23376):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your code adding the webView in a thread different than the UI thread, I mean, is that in a Task executor or something?

BTW. You can achieve layer effects using layouts and just setting the visible flags of elements as explained here: [Layout Layers? Z-Axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929412/android-layout-layers-z-axis)

Comment: thanks, however, i am not using any xml layout files.. , i'm using openGL , drawing all my background and picture... .

Comment: I have my setcontentview(glView) code placed in my framework class (GlGame) , which is called in each screen. later in this working screen, i want to add webView, that's why i tried to add layout, but the error came out.

Comment: I see GLThread in your code... You're adding views out of the ui thread. Try to avoid that.

Comment: And, maybe, try to use the xml layout. It's easier to handle when it comes to stack things or hide/show.

Comment: i try to modified my code, i moved all the code to my framework. but still got error... now i am thinking about two method, please tell me if it could make it and how.
1. In my framework class, set all the layout (glview and webview) so two layout is running in all my screen. so i need to hide webview layout and only display it in certain class i want.
2. don't modify the framework class, so i keep the glview, set as content view, and later in my certain screen , i add the second layout (webview)..
Which one would work ? could you give me example ?

Comment: I think the 1st one is better. I donno, though, what do you mean by "framework class". And you still keep talking about this or that class :(... See that Android runtime won´t allow you to create views in a different thread than that running the UI. Best approach is to create all views as stated in the activity lifecycle. Once I had a very heavy load of views and tried to deffer it to another thread ending up with a very big mess, lots of exceptions and never knowing where they´re risen.

Comment: If your GIGame inherits from View, just create a xml layout with that in it and add that as root view for all activities you´re using.

Comment: I am sorry, my framework class i talked about is my UI Thread i think, it's the first class run when app start. the layout is built inside that class. it also extend activity..  my other class is some classes that i want to call certain code to show/hide the webview layout..  (this framework actually from Mario Zachner'S Beginning Android Games Book). his forum is not so active though.
back to my GLGame Class (framework aka UI Thread), the layout building is in the oncreate method. i want to ask, which one should i hide ? the second layout which hold the webview or the webview itself ?

Comment: I tried to hide my webview 
`webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
it succeed, but i don't know how to make it visible again in certain times, when i call webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); in some places (inside the same class), the error came up said "only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." .. seems that i can't modify any of the view beside in the oncreate method.

Comment: Same thing!... The UI thread that should and MUST create and handle the views is the UI thread android provides, not yours, never yours. You can kind-of queue operations for the androidUI thread to execute with Activity::runOnUiThread(Runnable action). So, you can use your thread to do whatever your application does and, when you want to manipulate views, just: `myActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){button.setVisibility(View.GONE);})`

Comment: Thank you bro !, after trying some methods to access UI Thread, i finally can implement handler to set the visibility of my WebView.. 
I am really Happy as i finally can sleep well tonight. this things has burdened me for 3 days. Thank you again. wish u have a joyful day.