# Layering images in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio, layer

Currently I have a UI designed with imageviews, the problem is they cannot overlap or be layered. (Or if they can, I haven't figure out how) 
I'd like to do 3 layers, the bottom layer is the board,
The next layer is pieces, 
The next layer is a selected piece with valid moves.

My idea is that I will have listeners on the top layer only.

I am just looking for the best data structure to use for this, the app is a chesslike game I am working on developing.

If there is another approach that might be better I am all ears as well.

Thanks!

As requested code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Game Activity"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView22"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_whitesquare"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
        android:contentDescription="whitesquare"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView32"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_blacksquare"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:contentDescription="blacksquare"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView12"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_blacksquare"
        android:contentDescription="blacksquare"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView22" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView21"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_blacksquare"
        android:contentDescription="blacksquare"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView22"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView12" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView23"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_blacksquare"
        android:contentDescription="blacksquare"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView33"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView33" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView31"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_whitesquare"
        android:contentDescription="whitesquare"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView32"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView32" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView11"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_whitesquare"
        android:contentDescription="whitesquare"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView21" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView13"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_whitesquare"
        android:contentDescription="whitesquare"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView23"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView12" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView33"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_whitesquare"
        android:contentDescription="whitesquare"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView23"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView32"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView32" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/directions"
        android:id="@+id/directionsstring"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView21"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Startingpoint"
        android:src="@drawable/ni_pawn"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView11"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView12"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView12" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity :

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity

{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        final ImageView mStarting = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Startingpoint);

        final ImageView mCenterSq = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView22);
        final ImageView m12 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView12);


        mCenterSq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                m12.setImageResource(R.drawable.ni_blacksquare);
                mCenterSq.setImageResource(R.drawable.ni_portal);
                //center square turns into a portal when clicked.
                if (mStarting.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ni_whitesquare).getConstantState()) &&
                        mCenterSq.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ni_portal).getConstantState()) )
                {
                    mCenterSq.setOnClickListener(null);
                    return;
                }



                mStarting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    //Pawn selected
                    mStarting.setImageResource(R.drawable.ni_whitesquare);
                    m12.setImageResource(R.drawable.ni_greensquare);
                    mCenterSq.setImageResource(R.drawable.ni_greensquare);
                    if (mStarting.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ni_whitesquare).getConstantState()))
                    {
                        mStarting.setOnClickListener(null);
                    }


                    m12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)

                        {
                            if (m12.getDrawable().getConstantState().equals(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ni_greensquare).getConstantState()))
                            {
                                m12.setImageResource(R.drawable.ni_pawn);
                                mCenterSq.setImageResource(R.drawable.ni_portal);
                            }


                        }

                    });
                    }






                     });


            };
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code here? There are many approaches to layering layouts, but I'm not sure what you're trying that's not working correctly. Are you setting up your views programatically or using XML?

Comment: .xml and I'll post the activity that goes with it here in a second.

Comment: So all this code does i allow me to move a pawn two spaces into a portal where it then disappears. However, only one image shows at a time, and the green boxes for valid moves will not show what pieces (if any) are currently on the square. I was going to change the boxes to a green border, so that you can still see what pieces are on the square.

Comment: OK, sort of difficult to give you a one-off answer for your problem since it seems there are some pretty fundamental misunderstandings that need to be addressed before proceeding further.  I'll try to write an answer which points you in the right direction, but you'll need to do some reading of the docs to fully understand everything.

Comment: I have a github here : https://github.com/VhatAmI/OmniChess

I know my implementation is less then ideal and am all for seeing and understanding fundamental misunderstandings. I'm still trying to get everything tied together and working.

Comment: "it seems there are some pretty fundamental misunderstandings that need to be addressed before proceeding further." 

Can you elaborate on this? Examples? I appreciate the constructive criticism, but can you maybe take some code samples and show how you would improve them?  At least so I can look into the concepts that I need to improve on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For layering views, you might want to use a FrameLayout see this answer: [Layout Layers? Z-Axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929412/layout-layers-z-axis)

Also, if you're trying to set up a layout in which you have several consecutive views that need to be lined up one next to the other, the most appropriate element is usually a LinearLayout. LinearLayout will automatically set up your views in consecutive order in the order you declared them, according to the android:orientation attribute you set for it.

Overall, I'd suggest looking at the docs for each of these.  RelativeLayout is probably not the way to go since it involves a lot of managing of view positioning which just seems frivolous for what I think you are trying to do.  I hope this helps

Comment: Cool. The Z axis link looks like it might work for what I am trying to achieve. Thanks!